# Installing NVIDIA GEFORCE 1050 TI - Cannot Get To GUI

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, gui

I am trying to install an NVIDIA GEFORCE 1050 TI card on my system, but with the card installed, I can't access a GUI. Here is my system info:

> 15.4 GiB
>   Intel® Core™ i7-3770S CPU @ 3.10GHz × 8
>   Intel® Ivybridge Desktop
>   Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS 64-bit

I can get to BIOS and then to GRUB, but when I select to boot Ubuntu (I dual-boot, and the card works perfectly in Windows 10.), I only get a black screen. Trying to switch to the command line with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> does not work.

I found this mega-answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers) about getting drivers to work, but I can't figure out how to attempt these steps without a GUI.

I took the graphics card out and am in the system via the onboard Intel graphics at the moment. Is there anything that is recommended to install/uninstall in my system that would allow me to insert the card again and boot back to a sufficient GUI to attempt installing drivers?

Answer (score 1):

Since you can see GRUB, you can try following methods:

1. In GRUB, choose recovery mode and enter root shell like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYiTJtYmmzg .
2. In root shell, you may need to use `mount -o rw,remount /` to make the file system writable.
3. Open `/etc/default/grub`, find the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=...`. Change the line to: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='pcie_port_pm=off acpi_backlight=none acpi_osi=Linux acpi_osi=! acpi_osi="Windows 2009"'`

Then reboot again.